# Validations string of Page number input

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, loops, validation

I have a table called dttemp inside c# code, and a column of page number that I get from input. I want to validate function that tells me if there is duplicate string of number in the column. But turns out i create wrong one.

**but remember the input of page_number is a string**

The table looks like this:

| id | page_numb |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 |
| 1 | 10 |

So before I ask this I have already try mine with this loop:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < dttemp.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string[] abc = dttemp.Rows[i]["page_numb"].ToString().Split(',');

    for (int az = 0; az < abc.Length; az++)
    {
        int count = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < dttemp.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            if (dttemp.Rows[j]["page_numb"].ToString().Contains(abc[az].ToString()))
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }

            if (dttemp.Rows[j]["page_numb"].ToString().Contains(abc[az].ToString()) && count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is number of page been input more than once");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the function tells me there is same number too.
I think the code that I wrote validate between number 1 and 10 is same page number,
because the 10 having '1' in it, which is already input it in the first row belong with other number '**1**,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'.

Or maybe I am wrong. But the fact this function tells me I have same page number, which is wrong.

**I do new to the code though so this question maybe easy, I just want to know how can I fix this?**

Because the code will decide which page should I split from 1 file

Answer (score 1):

You should exclude the current Row in the inner for-loop.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < dttemp.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string[] abc = dttemp.Rows[i]["page_numb"].ToString().Split(',');

    for (int az = 0; az < abc.Length; az++)
    {
        int count = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < dttemp.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            // Exclude the current Row[i]
            if (j == i)
            {
                continue;
            }   

            if (dttemp.Rows[j]["page_numb"].ToString().Contains(abc[az].ToString()))
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }

            if (dttemp.Rows[j]["page_numb"].ToString().Contains(abc[az].ToString()) && count > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There is number of page been input more than once");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4efsMC)

Comment: thank you for your answer, its work, but its wrong.
when I add **'1' instead of '10'** on row number 2, its not stuck ,and not tell me there is same number, which is officialy 1 is the same number.

I want it code will say there is same number on dttemp if  in any row or in same row there is duplicate number